# Indexing through Android string resources

Tags: java, android

OK, I've got the code to allow me to index through the string resources. Now, how do I get the value of a specific resource item without knowing its name?

Here's the index loop:

```
Field[] fLst = R.string.class.getFields();

for(Field f : fLst){

  Log.i(dbgTag, "Field Entry: R.string." + f.getName());

}
```

Thanks for your efforts ...

Answer (score 2):

First, you know the resource's name. You are even putting it in your `Log` call. So, one option would be to use `getIdentifier()` on a `Resources` object (usually obtained by calling `getResources()` on your `Activity` or other `Context`).

Or, given that you have the `Field` object, call `f.getInt(R.string.class)`.

In either case (`getIdentifier()` or `getInt()`), you now have the numeric identifier of the resource, at which point you can call `getString()` on your `Activity` to get the actual `String` value.

Using reflection -- whether directly or via `getIdentifier()` -- is going to be slow. Please avoid the approach you are trying where possible. If you absolutely have to use reflection, be sure to cache your results, so you do not need to do the same lookups repeatedly.

Comment: Much appreciated. Of course, it looks so obvious now. 

And, yes, I'm fully aware of the expense of using reflection.

Comment: Off topic, but related to String resource:
If app is monolingual, and small Toasts like _"Please enter value less than 100"_ needs to be shown, should we still follow _String Resource_ methodology?