# Optimal way to iterate through a list of string resources

Tags: android

Given a list of string resources in strings.xml:

```
<string name="str_001">"aaaaaa"</string>
<string name="str_002">"bbbbbb"</string>
<string name="str_003">"cccccc"</string>
<string name="str_004">"dddddd"</string>
<string name="str_005">"eeeeee"</string>
<string name="str_006">"ffffff"</string>
```

What is the optimal way to fetch them iteratively (in a loop), *without* using reflection as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938218/indexing-through-android-string-resources)?

I know how to use `getString()` as in

```
String currentStr = getString(R.string.str_001);
```

But that `str_001` can't be generated at run time. (or can it?)

Comment: Would an array of Strings suffice? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Comment: @Maximus Yes! That strings.xml is in my control and I can change it to use `string-array` as you proposed. This is very elegant, thank you! Please post this as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting as requested by the asker from comments... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Answer (score 15):

Use `<string-array>` instead and then get the array as:

```
<string-array name="mystrings_array">

String[] myStrings = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mystrings_array);
```

Details here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Comment: Yours is great too (+1) but I can only accept one answer and @Maximus was first (by 372ms).